# How to convert a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm into yyyy-mm-dd in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I want to convert a date/time like "28-03-2020 00:00" into a date like "2020-03-28".
I tried both `lubridate` using

```
dmy_hm("28-03-2020 00:00")
```

and R base

```
as.Date(as.character("28-03-2020 00:00"), format = "%d-%m-%Y hh:mm")
```

both without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use a proper format in `as.Date` (check `?strptime`)

```
as.Date("28-03-2020 00:00", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
#Actually, this works as well
#as.Date("28-03-2020 00:00", format = "%d-%m-%Y")
#[1] "2020-03-28"
```

and for `lubridate` we can wrap `as.Date` to get date.

```
as.Date(lubridate::dmy_hm("28-03-2020 00:00"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime("28-03-2020 00:00")
#[1] "2020-03-28 EDT"
```

If the format is not present, use `addFormats`

```
addFormats("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```